# Python - edit text file - specific case

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file with log entries where I have specific ID's in every line.
My job is it to add a new log entry directly after the last one.

My Problem is, that in this has a Text under the last entry, so the last log entry ist not the last line of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#I hope it may work for you
test_string = "*  Test  ABC-564  2019-04-16\n"
end_condition = '*/\n'   #update as your condition

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.readlines()
f.close()

with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in txt:
        if line.endswith(end_condition):
            f.writelines(test_string)
        f.writelines(line)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Look up for `**/` and insert your line after the penultimate found

```py
with open('log.txt', 'r+') as f:
    txt = f.readlines()
    indexes = [i for i, s in enumerate(txt) if '**/\n' in s]
    txt.insert(indexes[len(indexes) - 2], ' *  version-126  JDE-384  2019-04-22\n')
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    for item in txt:
        f.write("%s" % item)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and use a temporary file.

```py
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
/************************************
    State          ID       Date      
____________________________________     
 *  1.00.00      JVL-344  2019-03-02     
 *  2.00.00      TSL-564  2019-04-16
 *  2.00.00      LLL-764  2019-04-17
 *  version-414  RSC-444  2019-04-21
 *  version-557  JDE-384  2019-04-22
 *************************************/
/*************************************
 *  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conset
 *  ur sadipscing elitrlabore et dol
 *  magna aliquyam
 *************************************/
'''
marker = ' *************************************/\n'

f = StringIO(data)
out = StringIO()
found_marker = False
for line in f:
    if line == marker and not found_marker:
        found_marker = True
        out.write(' *  new log entry 1\n')
        out.write(' *  new log entry 2\n')
        out.write(' *  new log entry 3\n')

    out.write(line)

print(out.getvalue())
```

Comment: My original text file has more then 150 lines so its bigger then the example

Comment: I'm gonna try this out